# Множество ip адресов у одного хоста

Tags: ip, wifi

Прошу объяснить причину данной, если можно так назвать, проблемы. Проверял настройки роутера и обнаружил, что у устройства несколько активных ip адресов. как такое может быть и является ли это проблемой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прям самому интересно, что это за чудо такое) А если на устройстве посмотреть IP-адрес в разные моменты времени - какой адрес там будет?

Comment: Еще один момент: во время обнаружения проверки к сети на обоих диапазонах было подключено 4 устройства в совокупности, а общее число указано 38 (в верхнем левом углу на скрине). Какой адрес на устройстве проверить смогу позже